# How to read and write open extension on Outlook event via office.js?

Tags: office-js, office-addins

I am currently working an an Outlook Add which needs to store some custom attributes for event instances, with events the the corresponding resource type [event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/event?view=graph-rest-1.0) is meant. These attributes should be available to follow up processes via Microsoft Graph. While I was successful in creating, modifying and reading open extensions via Graph, as described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/opentypeextension-post-opentypeextension?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) I struggle to achieved the same via the office API.
I checked the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/outlook?view=outlook-js-1.10) for any pointers but was successful.

Any hints how to achieve my tasks or whether it currently not supported are highly appreciated.

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Could you be more specific? What event handler do you need handle and data you are interested in?

Comment: Outlook has API to create custom properties that are specific to a particular item and specific to a mail add-in for Outlook. Please follow this document https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/outlook/office.customproperties?view=outlook-js-preview#get_name_

Comment: I edited my question to be more precise about my use case. @EugeneAstafiev

Comment: @OutlookAdd-insTeam-MSFT Thanks for the response, I will check in detail. As of now I was under the impression that these custom properties map to the legacy extended properties which use is discouraged if I understand these document right https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/extended-properties-overview?view=graph-rest-1.0

Answer (score 0):

I followed the approach proposed by @OutlookAdd-insTeam-MSFT and used the [custom properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/outlook/office.customproperties?view=outlook-js-preview). However I would still prefer to use open extensions, but this seems to be not supported at the moment.